# Setting up FlashDevelop so it makes a file that works on mobiles

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, actionscript, flashdevelop

I've got some Actionscript 3 code that works very well on desktops. Now I need to figure out how to make it work on mobile phones.

It's set up as a AS3 Project, and my assumption is that I'll need to make it a AIR Mobile AS3 App. Do I need to do a new project , or is there a way I can convert this project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to create a new "AIR Mobile AS3 App" (or "AIR Mobile Flex App" if you want to use Flex) project so that you can set the project settings for iOS/Android. Of course, you can share any AS3 code with your desktop app project.